# Django execute sql raw

Tags: sql-server, django, raw

I want to print the result by running a mssql query on any page in my postgresql project, how can I do it?

for exam.

```
SELECT  TOP(11) * FROM dbo.UserObject WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE u_logon_name='cc@gmail.com'
```

My default db setting is postgresql but I want to run mssql query;

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'ALIAS': 'XX',
        'USER': 'XX',
        'PASSWORD': 'XX',
        'HOST': 'XX',
        'PORT': 'XX',
    }
}
```

Comment: So you are asking how to use MS SQL Server instead of Postgres for your project?  What do you mean by "...running a mssql query .. in my postgresql project..."?

Comment: @squillman I use postgresql db by default in my project, but I want to run sql query in my views and print the result

Comment: So you are saying you want to use 2 different database platforms then?

Comment: Yes that's right